# Why is green the default solder mask color?

Tags: pcb, solder-mask

Solder masks can be had in many different colors. I have personally gotten white, black, red, and blue. But green is, by far, the most prevalent color on printed circuit boards, and the default at every fab house I've seen. Why green?

Comment: Today one of my engineers received boards with clear soldermask.  Trippy!  Didn't know clear was an option.  Also, OSH Park advertises by making all of its PCBs purple.

Comment: Clear! I forgot that one.

Comment: Black looks the best imho

Comment: At a couple of places that I've worked, alpha and beta versions of boards were red, and final release were green. That was to prevent engineering boards from getting out into the field (it made it easy to QC). I don't know why green was selected, however. I'm waiting for plaid soldermasks.

Comment: Agreed it's a duplicate.

Comment: Agreed it's a duplicate. VTC.